# How to create BPMN 2.0 files and visualisations programatically

Tags: jbpm, bpmn, business-process-management

I am working on a startup called http://tallyfy.com that's designed to make creating and doing business processes simple for non-technical people. It really is very simple.

Outside the realm of technical underpinnings - I want to look at the feasibility of transforming our "checklists on steroids" into a BPMN 2.0 specification - so that we an import and export from our internal format to standards-compliant format.

Is there any good open source framework or tools which allow me to specify a BPMN 2.0 compliant specification by API (programmatically) and when completed - allow me to generate the actual workflow visual as well?

I have taken a look at jBPM and various other open source frameworks, but can't seem to find a match for me. The need here is for something to be used "only for transformation" on the side, not as the primary UI for any user of the system. An internal, hidden engine - if you will.

Comment: Hi Amit, 
I have problem slightly similar to yours. I am looking for a parser which can parse the xml (.bpmn) file. I would like to find out different components in the business process pragmatically. Can you provide any useful lead?

Answer (score 2):

I'd recommend that you have a look at the BPMN Model API provided by the camunda.org project - and in particular its "fluent" builder API. It allows you to programmatically create BPMN 2.0 process definitions - and also to save them in BPMN XML format.

- https://github.com/camunda/camunda-bpmn-model
- http://docs.camunda.org/latest/guides/user-guide/#bpmn-model-api

However, I don't think it's possible to generate a "pretty" visual representation from that, in order to make it look nice you would need to load such a model into a BPMN standards compliant modeler like e.g. the camunda modeler, and manually arrange your activities, flows etc.

Comment: Hi Martin, I am watching this project. Does it look more suitable? It seems to be from camunda as well - https://github.com/bpmn-io/bpmn-js

Comment: Since a few years have passed, is there a go/python/C++ solution that can create bpmn files programatically? I need this with zeebe but only their java client can do it.

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at the [Eclipse BPMN2 Modeler](https://www.eclipse.org/bpmn2-modeler/). It is built with the [Eclipse Modeling Framework](https://eclipse.org/modeling/emf/), which basically means the whole BPMN diagram is represented in an object oriented data structure so it is easy to programmatically transform or even create a BPMN 2.0 process.